# Are there any peer-reviewed scientific publications lending credence to Christian miracles?

Tags: reference-request, miracles, science

Are there any publications in peer-reviewed scientific journals lending credence to any Christian miracle? For example, a peer-reviewed publication validating some "unexplainable" healing after intercessory prayer, or a peer-reviewed publication validating some "unexplainable" creative miracle, etc.

Comment: I suspect this would not satisfy your "peer reviewed" criteria, but you might be interested in Craig Keener's two-volume [Miracles](https://www.amazon.com/dp/0801039525).

Comment: For the Catholic Church to approve a miracle in the process of saint's canonization it goes through a rigorous process determining their authenticity. For miracle healings it considers only medically impossible and instantaneous cures (up to 1960s). What might most interest you are the many Eucharistic miracles which independent scientists have verified as living tissue enduring immense pain and the same blood type across all Eucharistic miracles. Research Eucharistic miracles.

Comment: @Glorius - would you be willing to develop your comment into a full-fledged answer to the question?

Comment: If you want peer-reviewed studies I doubt there are any and don't care to do it. I could write an answer about scientifically proven miracles and other trustworthy miracles this Sunday probably. If you want a collection of some of the most important miracles this is the best video I've seen so far: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xSif-6xkQ_A Best watched after: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JiMqzN_YSXU but that's not directly on miracles.

Answer (score -1):

Yes. You need look no further than here to get started: https://seanmcdowell.org/blog/a-remarkable-case-of-a-peer-reviewed-modern-miracle

Here are the words I used in my Yahoo search:

- peer
- reviewed
- scientific
- studies
- on
- the
- reality
- of
- miracles

I suggest you do a similar search and then provide your own answer to your own question.

Comment: The 'journal' linked to is 'Complementary Therapies in Medicine' and also lists articles on acupuncture, homeopathy, Baduanjin exercise and Shengmai injection. It is hardly a mainstream peer-review for accepted medical research.

Comment: @Nigel: I did say "get started." I did not mean my link is the one and only. It is, however, a start. The OP can always use my search words and then pick and choose which of the results of his search are of interest to him. Also, the OP's question reveals no amount of research on his/her part. A cursory search would have indicated a good-faith effort on his/her part in researching the question. Don